# How to create a static position for my text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in javascript, HTML, and CSS. I manage to do a simple animation program. But currently, what I need is, to display a text at the bottom of my map every time a function is executed. I am able to display is, but it keeps following my animation. Could you guys help me in my program and guide me what the problem?

```js
var move = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 97) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table1");
    }, 4000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 1";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 98) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table2");
    }, 4000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 2";

  }

  if (event.keyCode === 99) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 3";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 100) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table4");
    }, 2000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 4";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 101) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table5");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 5";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 102) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table6");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 6";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 103) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table7");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 7";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 104) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table8");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 8";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
    }, 0)
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(true);
    }, 4000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Going Back";
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("cu2+.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
}


/* Table 1 */

.robot_start_top {
  top: 260px;
  transition: top 2s;
}

.robot_start_left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 550px;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.robot_end_left {
  left: 680px;
}

.robot_end_top {
  top: 200px;
}

.robot_end_top2 {
  top: 55px;
}

.robot_end_table1 {
  top: 100px;
}


/* End of table 1, start of table 2 */

.robot1_end_left {
  left: 640px;
}

.robot_end_table2 {
  top: 80px;
}


/* End of table 2 Start of table 3 */

.robot_end_table3 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 550px;
}


/* End of table 3 Start of table 4 */

.robot_end_table4 {
  top: 55px;
  left: 590px;
}


/* End of Table 4 Start of Table 5 */

.robot_end_table5 {
  top: 45px;
  left: 530px;
}


/* End of Table 6 Start of Table 7 */

.robot_end_table6 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 500px;
}


/* End of Table 6 Start of Table 7 */

.robot_end_table7 {
  top: 40px;
  left: 480px;
}


/* End of Table 7 Start of Table 8 */

.robot_end_table8 {
  top: 55px;
  left: 440px;
}


/* End of Table 8*/
```

```html
<body onkeydown="move(event)">
  <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
    <img id="robot" style="width:30px; height:40px" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/android-png-android-logo-png-1024.png" alt="Android PNG" title="Image from pluspng.com">
    <p id="TableNumber"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: For starters, instead of timeouts, you probably want to be listening for [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) events. Something which that MDN article has a fairly nice example of for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple, actually. You just place the `p` tag outside your `div.app`. I also added CSS to style it. `position: fixed` to have the element (which I changed into a div instead) always be at a static place, no matter if the user scrolled or not. `bottom: 1rem` is a usual distance web designers use, which means the size of the body text. `left: 50%` moves the left side of the div to 50% of the screen, and to have it be centered, you need to move it back with `transform: translate`. `-50%` means move it to the left of a total of half the element's own width.

Another thing to consider, to make the javascript code easier to read is to create aliases for your keycodes. I added that into the code as well, just as an example.

If you're trying to make a game, I recommend you to read about [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

```js
var move = function(event) {
  let LEFT_ARROW = 37,
      UP_ARROW = 38,
      RIGHT_ARROW = 39,
      DOWN_ARROW = 40;
      
  if (event.keyCode === LEFT_ARROW || event.keyCode === 97) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_left");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table1");
    }, 4000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 1";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === UP_ARROW || event.keyCode === 98) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table2");
    }, 4000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 2";

  }

  if (event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW || event.keyCode === 99) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 3";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === DOWN_ARROW || event.keyCode === 100) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table4");
    }, 2000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 4";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 101) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table5");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 5";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 102) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table6");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 6";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 103) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table7");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 7";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 104) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_top");
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot1_end_left");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table3");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot_end_table8");
    }, 3200);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Table 8";
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_down");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function() {
      appDiv.classList.add("robot3_end_right");
    }, 0)
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.reload(true);
    }, 4000);
    document.getElementById("TableNumber").innerHTML = " Going Back";
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("cu2+.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-size: 980px 400px, cover;
}


/* ADDED CSS CODE */
#TableNumber {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* Table 1 */

.robot_start_top {
  top: 260px;
  transition: top 2s;
}

.robot_start_left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 550px;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.robot_end_left {
  left: 680px;
}

.robot_end_top {
  top: 200px;
}

.robot_end_top2 {
  top: 55px;
}

.robot_end_table1 {
  top: 100px;
}


/* End of table 1, start of table 2 */

.robot1_end_left {
  left: 640px;
}

.robot_end_table2 {
  top: 80px;
}


/* End of table 2 Start of table 3 */

.robot_end_table3 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 550px;
}


/* End of table 3 Start of table 4 */

.robot_end_table4 {
  top: 55px;
  left: 590px;
}


/* End of Table 4 Start of Table 5 */

.robot_end_table5 {
  top: 45px;
  left: 530px;
}


/* End of Table 6 Start of Table 7 */

.robot_end_table6 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 500px;
}


/* End of Table 6 Start of Table 7 */

.robot_end_table7 {
  top: 40px;
  left: 480px;
}


/* End of Table 7 Start of Table 8 */

.robot_end_table8 {
  top: 55px;
  left: 440px;
}


/* End of Table 8*/
```

```html
<body onkeydown="move(event)">
  <div class="robot_start_left robot_start_top" id="app">
    <img id="robot" style="width:30px; height:40px" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/android-png-android-logo-png-1024.png" alt="Android PNG" title="Image from pluspng.com">
  </div>

  <div id="TableNumber"></div>
</body>
```